# Да сколько же можно [работа]ть?

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Есть метка [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0). Из 81 вопроса закрыто 79. Полагаю, нынче эта тема выходит за рамки основного сайта. За сим предлагаю её сжечь.

Comment: @Kromster ..так?

Comment: Убрал метку с двух незакрытых вопросов. Теперь решение будет легче принять, я думаю.

Comment: 79 вопросов предлагается удалить?

Comment: @Nofate вопрос же о сжигании метки, а не вопросов. Но если хотите - можете и вопросы поджечь. мне лично их не жалко)

Comment: Но много вопросов только с меткой [tag:работа]. Вопрос нельзя оставить без метки совсем.

Comment: @Nofate "untagged" ?

Comment: @Nofate, ну так удалить сами вопрос же!

Comment: @Nofate, _79 вопросов предлагается удалить?_ - и больше удаляли :-)

Comment: может проще вопросы перенести на мету?

Comment: @AK ну судя по одному из ответов в данном топике - это для кого-то будет грандиозным потрясением. Да и абсолютно все эти вопросы тащить на мету не имеет смысла. некоторые из них там реально треш и угар даже для старого хэшкода. надо, если тащить, то для начала определиться что именно на мету тащить...либо решить что с ними делать ... кстати https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39823438#39823438

Answer (score 4):

Хватит уже удалять всё подряд. Тащите вопросы на мету с [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5).

**UPDATE: Как недавно выяснилось, перенос на мету приводит к потере репутации у участвовавших в вопросе людей, поэтому этот вариант неприменим. По крайней мере до тех пор, пока не будет найден способ обойти эту проблему.**

Comment: [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе] тоже надо удалить :D

Comment: @D-side нет работы, нет и диалогов!

Comment: Надо просто пофиксить механизм миграции, чтобы репа сохранялась так же как это делается для удаленных постов. Но в общем проблема сильно преувеличена. Я не увидел какой-то чрезмерной потери репы у брмалея. Надо еще посчитать сколько было получено после принятия решения об оффтопичности проблемных тем. Наверное тоже немало. Но почему-то вопроса об откате не стоит.

Comment: @alexolut, потому что нельзя забирать честно заработанное.

Answer (score -4):

Дел то других нет, видимо, кроме как жечь. Уже столько сожгли, в т.ч. при этом кстати горят и рейтинги полученные на этих вопросах/ответах.

Мне лично уже пополам/все равно, но не думаю, что у участника набравшего на этом полсотню голосов - приятно видеть свои сгоревшие рейтинги.

Давайте, жгите дальше.

**Update**
Пример сожжения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но ведь жгутся не вопросы, а метки.

Comment: Жгутся переносом на мету, при этом горят рейтинги - не в курсе?

Comment: `Жгутся переносом на мету` - кто такое сказал? вы? можно поставить метку "old-offtopic-questions" и лок на вопросах и радоваться дальше?

Comment: @alexolut нет, это вопрос вообще про сжигание метки))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да [по твоей просьбе же только что](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39823223#39823223) перенесли [раз](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5844/178988) и [два](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5835/178988), а теперь _"кто сказал?"_ - шикарная позиция!

Comment: Тьху. Вопросы разные, а ответ универсальный.

Comment: @Qwertiy заметь там написано "Может им стоит какую-то метку по вашему усмотрению поставить и убрать "обучение"" а не "надо перенести их за ненадобностью". Акцент я специально сделал на изначальную банально смену метки на какую-либо. Но это не обязательное действие

Comment: Жгите, Шура, жгите дальше...